# Devtools console - Prevent console from switching context to iFrame automatically?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Looks like Chrome introduced a feature (somewhat recently?) that automatically switches the context of the console to whatever is selected on the DOM explorer. This causes some annoying issues as iFrames start loading and are selected automatically after a page refresh.

Is there any way to keep the context at `top` level?

Example of what happens after a page refresh below:

[image: Example of this behaviour]

EDIT:
I've tried the suggestion from @wOxxOm and disabled the `Strict site isolation` flag. Also disabled `Top document isolation` for good measure, but the issue still seems to happen.
[image]

Comment: https://crbug.com/821515 - the bug is present only if you enable "Strict site isolation" in chrome://flags so simply don't enable it.

Comment: That's weird - it's disabled under the flags already. I haven't changed any chrome flags so it's running the current default.

Comment: Uhm, Chrome enables this flag internally for random users unless you opt-out via chrome://flags/#site-isolation-trial-opt-out

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, I've explicitly set it to disabled but the issue still seems to be happening. Also updated my questions, just to double check I'm disabling the correct flags.

Comment: Like I said, Chrome enables it internally unless you opt-out via another flag in my comment above.

Comment: Probably a very dumb question, but do I just hit chrome://flags/#site-isolation-trial-opt-out  to opt out? Otherwise I just the generic `flags` page when I open that

Comment: Paste that in the address bar and it'll scroll to the flag, then change its value to "opt out".

Comment: Oh I see, the opt out only shows up on Canary, not the regular client. I'll just use Canary for now, until that bug is fixed.
Thanks a lot for your help @wOxxOm !

Answer (score 1):

Disabling 'Top document isolation' flag seems to work fine.

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.